# Cacti CentOS Issues

Tags: linux, networking, centos, monitoring, cacti

So I'm running `CentOS 6.5` and I'm trying to install and configure `Cacti`. I keep running into the same issue repeatedly.

**Setup MySQL Server for Cacti**

```
mysqladmin -u root password STRONGPASSWORD1
```

After executing this step I receive:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

When I try these steps:

**Create MySQL Cacti Database**

```
# mysql -u root -p
mysql> create database cacti;
mysql> GRANT ALL ON cacti.* TO cacti@localhost IDENTIFIED BY ‘STRONGPASSWORD1’;
mysql> FLUSH privileges;
mysql> quit;
```

Starting with `mysql -u root -p` I can login with `STRONGPASSWORD1` but when I try:

```
create database cacti;
```

It gives me this message:

```
create database cacti;
ERROR 1007 (HY000): Can't create database 'cacti'; database exists
```

Onto the next step:

```
GRANT ALL ON cacti.* TO cacti@localhost IDENTIFIED BY ‘STRONGPASSWORD1’;ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '‘STRONGPASSWORD1’' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issues you are having are more with MySQL than with Cacti.

In regards to the ERROR you are receiving:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '‘STRONGPASSWORD1’' at line 1

It seems to be the quotes you are using try using '' instead of ‘’